# Eater trashed during the run: still can't acess card during the run?

Tags: android-netrunner

A runner makes run on a server protected by two ices. The second one is [Nebula](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Nebula). The runner uses the [Eater](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=eater) to break all subroutines on the first ice. Than runner encounters [Nebula](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Nebula) and it destroys eater. What happens with the [Eaters](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=eater) effect "you cannot access more than 0 cards for the remainder of this run". Nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still wouldn't be able to access cards, because conditional effects of cards do not disappear when the card is trashed. Same way as with [Sneakdoor Beta](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=sneakdoor) - if you start a run with it then it gets trashes midrun, you still apply it's access replacement effect for this run.